# Pandas: Finding counts of occurrences of all 3-char sequence substrings from a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a column `peptide` in pandas dataframe.

```
    peptide
0   AASAASHHHS
1   AHSDDHDCN
2   DNNFNMLIF
```

and another list of alphabets

```
alphabets = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'Y']
```

from the alphabets list i have created all the possible triple combinations from this code

```
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(alphabets, repeat = 3)]
```

length of keywords is 8000 and it looks like this

```
['AAA','AAC','AAD','AAE', 'AAF','AAG','AAH'......]
```

I want each element of keywords to be search in `peptide` row 1 then 2 and then 3 and upto so on if element is found I want the element and its frequency otherwise frequency should be zero.

I want resulting dataframe like this:

```
AAL AAK AAM AAF AAP AAS AAT AAW   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (8000)
0    2   0   0   0   2  0    0    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (8000)
0    0   1   0   0   0  0    0    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (8000)
3    0   0   0   0   0  0    1    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . (8000)
```

A dataframe like this with all the keywords 8000 words as column names and row wise frequencies from `peptide` column. This dataframe is sample and not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column `pep3` with all 3-character substrings of `peptide`.  Then, use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand the list of substrings in `pep3` into separate rows. Then, create the pivot table using [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), as follows:

```
df['pep3'] = df['peptide'].map(lambda x: [x[0+i:3+i] for i in range(0, len(x) - 2)])
df2 = df.explode('pep3')
df2['count'] = 1

df3 = df2.pivot_table(index='peptide', columns='pep3', values='count', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).astype(int).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)

            AAS  AHS  ASA  ASH  DCN  DDH  DHD  DNN  FNM  HDC  HHH  HHS  HSD  LIF  MLI  NFN  NML  NNF  SAA  SDD  SHH
peptide                                                                                                            
AASAASHHHS    2    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
AHSDDHDCN     0    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
DNNFNMLIF     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
```

To further extend the columns to all the 3-character substring in the list `keywords`, we can use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), as follows:

```
df3.reindex(keywords, axis=1, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

**Final Result:**

```
    peptide   AAA AAC AAD AAE AAF AAG AAH AAI AAK ... YYM YYN YYP YYQ YYR YYS YYT YYV YYW YYY
0   AASAASHHHS  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   AHSDDHDCN   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   DNNFNMLIF   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 rows × 8001 columns
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you want to check whether an element is a part of elements of `peptide` column, and you want the frequency of each combination.
For example, if you want frequency 1 for `AAS` and `HHS` elements because they both are in the first row of the peptide column.

Here is my solution-

```py
d = dict()
l = list(df['peptide'])
for i in keywords:
    d[i] = 0
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i in l[j]:
            d[i] += 1
    if d[i] == 0:
        del d[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the task correctly, you wanna know frequency of each keyword occurence. Then you can do this:

```
freq_df = pd.DataFrame()
freq_df['keyword'] = keywords
freq_df['freq'] = None

for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
    freq = 0
    for p in peptides.iloc[0]:
        freq += p.count(keyword)
    freq_df['freq'][i] = freq
```

It will give you the table of form:

```
     keyword freq
0        AAA    0
1        AAC    0
2        AAD    0
3        AAE    0
4        AAF    0
...      ...  ...
7995     YYS    0
7996     YYT    0
7997     YYV    0
7998     YYW    0
7999     YYY    0

[8000 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to notice, that in this solution you count number of occurences of keyword in the peptide for each peptide, and then sum it.
But the problem here is that by using "string.count()" function you will calculate only separate occurences. For example, string 'AAAAAA' will have only 2 occurences of "AAA" substring, not 4. You can calculate the number manually, if it is necessary for you. Just replace p.count(keyword) to the cycle like:

```
freq_df = pd.DataFrame()
freq_df['keyword'] = keywords
freq_df['freq'] = None

for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
    freq = 0
    for p in peptides.iloc[0]:
        for j in range(len(p)-len(keyword)+1):
            if p[j:j+len(keyword)] == keyword:
                freq += 1
    freq_df['freq'][i] = freq
```

Comment: You can also use regular expressions to find substrings in a string if you wish, btw. There is a library called "re" in python.